# simplify-js package. Always return 2 points of polygon

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have got array of points (x,y) and i need to reduce points of polygons.
i would like use Simplify.js (It uses a combination of Douglas-Peucker).
But i have got problem:

```
let test = 
[ { x: 33.56257055900005, y: 44.83995926300003 },
                    .....
                    ..... more than 7k points
  { x: 33.56257055900005, y: 44.83995926300003 } ];

let simplified = simplify(test, 1, true);
```

always return 2 points (first, and last).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simplify-js
http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/

what it is not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first remove last point of test to convert your polygon to polyline, then balance your `tolerance`. If your points are cordinate on the earth, 1 means at least 50 mi (80 km)!!!
Try 0.001 for tolerance

```
let simplified = simplify(test, 0.001, true);
```

Comment: god damn, I've been stuck with this for the past 3 hours, thank you so much.